# asp.net textarea line feed and preventing postback on return key

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textarea, postback

I have an ASP.net web application with numerous pages.
Most of them have Multiline APS.net textbox and standard text box. Pressing the return key has unexpected result depending on browsers, page, last control used. It can fire any control either the master or the child page. Sometimes hitting the return key even fire the logout control.

So to prevent this I added:

```
body onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13)"
```

In the the master page body tag as recommended in many places, which works like a charm.
However, this cause the the return key not to respond to line feed in text area. 
Users need to be able to insert line feed in Text area ( TextBoxMode.MultiLine)

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
Keep:

```
body onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13)"
```

this will disable any post back using Return Key,
Then add to any multi line textbox the following attribute:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "EnterEvent(event,this)");
```

with the following javascript:

```
// add Line feed in text area.
function EnterEvent(e,ctl) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == 13) {

    var st1 = $(ctl).textrange('get', 'start');
    var l = ctl.value.length;
    if (st1 < l) {
        $(ctl).textrange('replace', '\n');
        $(ctl).textrange('set', st1 + 1, 0);
    }
    else {
        ctl.value = ctl.value + '\n';
    }
    }

}
```

this "manually" insert LF  on return key up event.

Comment: what if user presses enter in the middle of the text?

Comment: This is correct, in the edited version, i use jquery textrange to insert the '\n' in the middle then set cursor after it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
window.onload = function() {
    setEvent("text", onKeyDown);
}

function onKeyDown()
{
   return (event.keyCode!=13)
}
```

Which will cancel return button in only textboxes

Comment: Thanks, There is an major improvement but this treat Textarea and input type="text" the same. and incoherent post back still happen on focused empty single line text.  I tried to change Text to textarea. but is does not work.

Comment: @Lambda - Unable to understand what you mean :(

Comment: What I need is something that stop all key13 postback on everything but Let me insert line feed in textarea. Your solution does stop postback when no text is selected, but still create post back when a single line of text ( input type=text) is selected. I think I may have a solution by separating onkeydown event from onkeyup event, also not working yet.